# What is the difference between rendering from a JSX and from a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following:

```
const Foo = ({ bar }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {bar}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What is the difference between `<Foo bar='something' />` and `Foo({ bar: 'something' })`?

```
render (
  <>
    {/* Is there any difference for the following two? */}
    <Foo bar='something' />
    {Foo({ bar: 'something' })}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Foo({ bar: 'something' })`, and render the result in your component, then you are essentially no longer treating `Foo` as its own React component, and instead assimilating it into the calling component. In effect, it would be the same as putting the result of calling the function inline in the parent component.

On the other hand, when you use `<Foo>` in JSX syntax, or equivalently, `React.createElement(Foo)`, then `Foo` is treated as its own component, which means that it can make use of features like React Hooks.

In the simplest case as you have shown, there is really no difference, but in practice, it generally makes sense to use the JSX syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This expects the foo function is going to return an UI (e.g. Card, div).

`<Foo bar ='something'/>`

This does not expect the foo function to return an UI, ONLY RUN THE FUNCTION WITHIN IT.

`<Foo({bar:'something'})`

Comment: both actually can be used. but for programmer's convenience, easier to read and to make it consistent, we usually use JSX if we know we are going to get an UI.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I think I should phrase my question a little bit better. I think I understand why the former is used rather than the latter, but I wonder is there any technical differences between the two.

Comment: No technical diffrence. it's just the matter of use case only. pls do upvote the answer if u are satisfied with the answer. XD